# Mac Apache web server won't start anymore and can't find any web directories

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, osx-yosemite

I'm on Mac Yosemite 10.10.5. Apache web server suddenly no longer starts. I tried changing the port to 8080. Also tried sudo apachectl stop and sudo apachectl start. Still won't open.

I thought this may have happened after adding a new printer and enabling print sharing. I turned that off and it still won't start. I can't remember which command I ran that gave me this message with some more details.

[image]

UPDATE: When I use `sudo apachectl start`, I noticed the server is accessible through the browser even though the interface still says STOPPED, but when I go to localhost/webdirectory I just get not found.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 26):

After 48 hours of research, I found this working solution, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582504/xampp-apache-webserver-localhost-not-working-on-mac-os): disable OSX's built-in Apache server.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

This allowed XAMPP to start on 80, while [POW](http://pow.cx/) runs on 20559.

Comment: This still works even on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6. After update to 10.13.5 my MAMP apache server was unable to load on port 80, and after running this command I as able to run it normally

Comment: I am glad to know that this still works for you @IvanHušnjak

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day :D

Comment: oh my gosh thank you so much don't know why but your solution helped me too!

Comment: @dulerong I'm glad this helps, even after 3 years and some months now.

Comment: Literally had the same problem after upgrading from Big Sur to Ventura.

Comment: Thank you for this! After executing this command I did "brew services restart httpd" and after that my localhost was working again.

Comment: Wow this is the only answer that actually helped!

Answer (score 8):

You have to run the command as the root user.

```
sudo apachectl stop

sudo apachectl start
```

Comment: The first screen shot shows a permission error.  What is the error when you use sudo?

Comment: This is what I'm getting: Omars-iMac:~ Omar$ sudo apachectl start
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Operation already in progress

Comment: I've added the screenshots above. The server still shows stopped and it no longer opens any web directories inside the localhost/

Comment: "The server still shows stopped" .... how are you getting this info?  I don't see any screenshots showing that it is stopped.

Comment: I see your latest screen shot.  It seems odd that Server Manager shows that it is stopped but you get a webpage and "Operation already in progress" error.

Comment: Also, localhost is not a fully qualified domain name.  I believe the message "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name..." is more of a warning than an actual error message and should not stop the server from running.

Comment: I would recommend setting the ServerName to the local IP address like it recommends in the configuration file rather than setting it to ServerName localhost.  However, if your server is assigned an IP address by DHCP  you will need to make sure that it always gets the same IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a command that should locate your issue(s). In the Terminal enter:
apachectl configtest

Comment: When adding answers to older questions with existing answers it is useful to point out what new things your answer brings to the question. In this case Radu's answer already appears to include `apachectl configtest` and it discusses how to interpret the results.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous experience running the command `apachectl configtest` will show any configuration errors you might have. If everything is ok it will print `Status OK`, otherwise it will show you the config error(s). Fix those and then retry `apachectl start`.

Comment: I'm getting: |||| AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Omars-iMac.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK.  |||| the server's name is: ServerName localhost

Comment: Well, that error appears because your `ServerName` is not setup in your `httpd.conf` file. You will need to edit `httpd.conf` and add the line `ServerName localhost` right after `ServerAdmin`. Save and restart apache.

Comment: I added another screenshot. I already have ServerName localhost listed there

Comment: Assuming that you can run commands as root, could you please run `httpd -t`. Just making sure that the syntax you are using in your `httpd.conf` file is correct.

Comment: Weird I get the same error: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Omars-iMac.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: I don't want to sound patronising, but you are certain that the httpd.conf file that you are editing is the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` ? Because it seems like your `httpd.conf` file is ignored.

Comment: Sorry guys, does it help to see all my httpd.conf. I feel like something else is going on: [link]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DVxWRgorznWnmItZkOTRjkPslPcTL8O5cYeLGwKgmmM/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

Comment: I have two it seems: xamppfiles > etc > httpd.conf and xamppfiles > apache2 > conf >  httpd.conf. There seems to be htdocs folder under both areas, but all my web directories are really here: xamppfiles > htdocs

Comment: If you are using XAMPP, then I think the config file that you should be editing is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` (assuming that you kept the default path on XAMPP installation). You also might want to try `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start` Just in case you have multiple Apache installations on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with following code in terminal. You can try it.

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

Solvet this by run `service` directly trougth `.plist` file.

After that, service explane me what happen exactly.

In my case, i am was delete `apache2` folder in `/var/log`.

When i was try run httpd with by command:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

answer was empty.

Open `org.apache.httpd.plist` in editor,
you need `<string>` with path to service after `<key>ProgramArguments\<key>`
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start Apache without DocumentRoot, It's just a trick.

```
sudo apachectl -T
```