# Error starting "XAMPP" stack: cannot start stack: ssh not accessible

Tags: ssh, xampp, localhost

Hello recently i installed XAMPP on my MAC and it was working fine then it stopped working with the following error:

> INFO: Starting "XAMPP" stack ERROR: Error starting "XAMPP" stack:
>   cannot start stack: ssh not accessible

I tried to reinstall XAMPP still the problem exists, i search around for a fix but had no luck anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

i am same with you ,i found the answer in https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=257470&sid=05104063fe8770ead60022422886717c

The folder is in your /Users/ folder but it is hidden. You can remove it from a Terminal

```
rm -rf ~/.bitnami
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try putting off your firewall and retry , see if it works

Comment: How would the firewall come into play in this scenario?

Comment: I believe it blocks a connection as it recognizes as a 'dangerous/harmful' source or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=257806&sid=dabee0c749730a85d36f630aff1e524e#p263956) if it's a firewall problem.

To turn off the firewall:

1. Go to **System Preferences**
2. Then, **Security&Privacy**
3. Third tab, **Firewall**

---

Also, it might be due to built-in Apache server. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582504/xampp-apache-webserver-localhost-not-working-on-mac-os/11720851#11720851).

You can try:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

It allows you to use a different port, which is *80*.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was my Express VPN was on.  I turned off VPN and the error goes away.